# Switch-on-strings Java7 - архив переписки JSR 334

Tags: java, строки, switch

Здравствуйте. Может ли мне кто-нибудь объяснить небольшой момент в переписки, касательно критики и предложений данного нововведедения switch-on-strings в 7 пакете Жабы, в 334 coin project 334 JSR ?

процитирую:

```
Now that we plan to have closures, do we still need strings-in-switch?
Won't a string-to-function map be about as fast (though maybe less
convenient)? I don't know what the use cases are for
strings-in-switch, but the feature already felt a bit low-benefit to
me, and seems even more so now with closures.
```

[ссылка на источник](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-December/002600.html)

Что такое понятие closures, и почему в случае его реализации, задается вопрос, существует ли необходимость в данной опции-свичире ?
Какая между ними связь, объясните для непонимающего.
И так же на счет вопроса не будет ли string-to-function map не менее быстрым.

Может кто небольшое введение сделать для понимания данного коммента ?
Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу ошибаться, но мне кажется, здесь речь идет о замыканиях, т.е. лямбдах.

Пример, где `switch` может быть заменен лямбда-функцией.

```
public static String caseOnString(String str) {
    switch (str) {
        case "hello":
            return "world";
        case "bye":
            return "country";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}

public static String mapOnString(String str) {
    Function<String, String> map = s -> {
        if (s.equals("hello"))
            return "world";
        if (s.equals("bye"))
            return "country";
        return "";
    };

    return map.apply(str);
}
```

Comment: В таком виде это не отличается от if-else без лямбд. Речь, конечно, о варианте как у @Roman.

Comment: ну да, его вариант больше похож на правду

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, имели в виду следующее: если у нас есть переменная `String str`, то вместо

```
switch (str) {
    case "one":
        System.out.println(1);
        break;
    case "two":
        System.out.println(2);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("?");
}
```

предлагали писать что-то вроде такого (closures - это замыкания, а в случае java - лямбды, хоть они и не полноценные замыкания):

```
Map<String, Runnable> switchMap = new HashMap<>();
switchMap.put("one", () -> System.out.println(1));
switchMap.put("two", () -> System.out.println(2));
switchMap.getOrDefault(str, () -> System.out.println("?")).run();
```